# Custom Mongodb _id in Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there any way to specify a custom id (like a string or specific number) in _id field when using Mongodb with Node.js.

I have tried `{_id: new ObjectId("any string or number")}` but it did not work.

this is my cut Code:

```
    const db = client.db("db1");
    const collection1 = db.collection("collection1");
    await collection1.insertOne({
      _id: new ObjectId("any string"),
      name: req.body.name,
      age: req.body.age,
    });
    res.status(200).send("Data Inserted");
    client.close();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "costume id", probably a custom ID?

Comment: It is valid to specify a custom value for the `_id` field. The value can be of any type _except_ an array.

Comment: Can you provide me with a code please? I can specify a custom value for ```_id``` in the shell, but not in my express.js app. Note: I use react.js as forontend, express.js as backend and axios to send request to the backend.